# Как это называется

Tags: значение-слов

Подскажите, как это называется. От чего утка плавает. Что делал слон, когда пришел Наполеон

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы о том, как называется такая форма загадки?
"Каламбур" не пойдет? "Игра слов"?

Comment: каламбур - это пойдет